# How to load large bitmap in FMX (fire monkey)

Tags: image, delphi, bitmap, firemonkey

I am trying to create a Manga viewer which needs to load `JPG` images with large sizes like 1000*16000, my application is in delphi FMX and i have already tried using `TImage`, `TImageViewer`, `TImageControl` but all of them use `TBitmap` which trims the size to `8192` after loading the image
I tried searching for image libraries but i was unable to find anything for `FMX (firemonkey)`
I was thinking maybe i could load the image in a `Memory stream` and then copy and draw it in smaller sizes to several bitmaps ? but i don't how can i read and parse the memory stream and only pick to a certain clean height !
In the end i'm looking for a way to load and show these large (`1000*16000`) images in `Delphi FMX`
I am using delphi 10.2.3
Thanks.

**Edit 01 :**
I think i have found a way that might make things easy, i added the `Vcl.Imaging.jpeg` to uses clause in the `FMX (FireMonkey)` and then i used `TJPEGImage` and loaded the image, and i printed the width and height and they are correct and not trimmed ! so i was thinking, maybe i can read each pixel from `TJPEGImage.canvas` and then print it into `FMX TBitmap` ?, what do you think about this approach ?, do you know a good way to copy the data inside `TJPEGImage` to `FMX TBitmap` ?

**Edit 02 :**
I have found a new solution, the `TBitmapSurface`, it seems this class doesn't have the `TBitmap` limitations and i was able to load the image inside of it without getting trimmed ! but there is a problem! how can i give this to `TImage` ? if i simply say `Image.bitmap.assign(TBitmapsurface)`, then the image gets trimmed again ! so it seems the only possible way is rewriting the `TImage` so it uses `TBitmapSurface` instead of `TBitmap`, any help regarding this issue is appreciated, thanks.
Here is the code for the `TBitmapSurface` :

```
bitmapSurf := TBitmapSurface.Create;
TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromFile(path, bitmapSurf);
```

Comment: There are multiple formats, even within `JPG`, not to mention compression and color format. Reading an image via a stream will be a major undertaking to support those different formats. Which platform(s) do you intend to target?

Comment: @JerryDodge For now Desktop but i hope to target android after this, i even have a working prototype which works with normal mangas which have small images and yes indeed reading via stream will be a very hard thing to do which is why i am looking for a better way!, by the way, what do think about loading the image into a stream, and then drawing it manually ?, is this possible ?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But that's the same thing that I just described - you'd need to parse it and interpret everything yourself. Start by studying JPG specifications. Or continue searching for a third-party library.

Comment: Also, keep in mind memory limitations. You say "For now Desktop", but if you have any slightest intention to target, for example, Android, you will have to design it so from the beginning - and Android has limited memory. That's why it get scaled down by default. Take whatever the file size is, and imagine loading that data into memory.

Comment: @JerryDodge Hmm, If i forget the android for now, is there a way to use windows api to do this ?, i mean why is it so hard to load/copy only a part of the image ?

Comment: The same applies for Windows - you just have more memory to work with. Even if you split the image up into smaller pieces, it will still consume the same memory (or even more, actually).

Comment: @JerryDodge For now the memory is not a problem, the images usually size under 1mb and even when viewing i only load the next 2 image, and then as the user scrolls down, i load the next ones, so i don't really have memory problem for now.

Comment: Refer to my second comment above. However, that's very broad, and don't expect us to pick a third-party library for you or write it for you - both are off-topic here. There may be a trick in FMX to be able to handle this, but I just don't know of such a trick.

Comment: you can use imagemagick (https://www.imagemagick.org) that support tera pixels :) for using it in delphi, you can take a look at https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe

Comment: Btw iOS has even more memory restrictions than Android. And middle iOS devices has less RAM than Android middle devices.

Comment: I tried a new approach which i think can work, please read Edit 01 in the main post.

Comment: Also, you can look at OpenGL libraries to paint image on any canvas.

Comment: Using VCL from FMX is a terrible choice. `TBitmapSurface` sure sounds like the way to go - you just need to proportionally re-size the image to fit in the user's view. Remember, `TImage` is only a visual control for the user to see something - it is not where you should be storing your primary data. Just copy over the region of the main image that you want the user to see, and the rest would be cropped out. No need to draw something larger than the user can even see.

Comment: @JerryDodge How can i copy the region of the main image i want from `TBitmapsurface` ?, i couldn't find any function except a `pixel` which takes an `x` and `y` and return a `cardinal value`, do i have to read it pixel by pixel and put it in the `TImage.bitmap` ?, any help tips is apprecaited, thx

Comment: TBitmap has a special function called `AsignFromSource` which should be used for assigning contents from `TBitmapSurface`. Now I don't know if it might have the same limitation than the Assign method has and I can't test this out properly since I don't have any big enough image for testing.

Comment: @SilverWarior There is no function called `AssignFromSource`, but if you mean the `Assign`, i have already tried that and the `TBitmap` trims the data after the `Assign`, so its of no use.

Comment: @aliahmadi Yes there is. I have been looking at it yesterday in source code of FMX.Graphics. But looking at documentation now I see that this is a protected method and therefore intended to be used internally in TBitmap class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `FMX.Graphics.TBitmap` which has a size limitations of `8192 * 8192`, `FMX.Surface.TBitmapSurface` seems to support up to `16k * 16k` and possibly even more (i haven't tested), so using `FMX.Surface.TBitmapSurface` you can load the image without getting trimmed, and then you can easily split it into two `FMX.Graphics.TBitmap` (or possible more parts using the same approach)
**Below you can see the code which first loads the `JPG` into `TBitmapSurface`, and then the code which splits that into two `TBitmap` :**

```
var
  srce, dest: TBitmapSurface;
  path: string;
  scan: integer;
  w, h1, h2: integer;
begin
  path := 'C:\tmp\Imgs\res.bmp';
  srce := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromFile(path, srce); 

  dest := TBitmapSurface.Create;

  // first half
  w := srce.Width;
  h1 := srce.Height div 2;
  dest.SetSize(w, h1, TPixelFormat.RGBA);
  for scan := 0 to h1-1 do
    Move(srce.Scanline[scan]^, TBitmapSurface(dest).Scanline[scan]^, srce.Width * 4);
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(dest); 

  // second half
  h2 := srce.Height - h1;
  dest.SetSize(w, h2, TPixelFormat.RGBA);
  for scan := h1 to srce.Height-1 do
    Move(srce.Scanline[scan]^, TBitmapSurface(dest).Scanline[scan-h1]^, srce.Width * 4);
  Image2.Bitmap.Assign(dest);

end;
```

*This answer was provided using the comments on the first post and the answer to my other question:*
[How to draw FMX.Surface.TBitmapSurface on FMX.Graphics.TBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523321/how-to-draw-fmx-surface-tbitmapsurface-on-fmx-graphics-tbitmap/51526855#51526855)