# How to draw FMX.Surface.TBitmapSurface on FMX.Graphics.TBitmap

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, firemonkey

Follwing on:
[How to load large bitmap in FMX (fire monkey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466186/how-to-load-large-bitmap-in-fmx-fire-monkey)
I have come to a need to draw whats on `TBitmapSurface` on the `FMX.Graphics.TBitmap`, i have found a lot of answer regarding this on the web, but they are either in `VLC` instead of `FMX` or their goal is `saving` and `loading` instead of drawing on a `TBitmap`, which is why i asked a new question here.
Now here is my current code for loading my image on the `TBitmapSurface` :

```
var
  bitmapSurf: TBitmapSurface;
  path: string;
begin
  path := 'image.jpg';
  bitmapSurf := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromFile(path, bitmapSurf);
end;
```

Now after searching for a bit i found that i can use `Scanline` on the `TBitmapSurface`, but i didn't know how to use it to draw on the `TBitmap`, on the web some people had used `TBitmap.canvas.draw`, but such a thing doesn't exist on the `FMX`!.
**In the end my goal is to draw a very large image (1000*16000) which is loaded in the `TBitmapSurface` on more then `1` `TBitmap`** (because `TBitmap` doesn't support more then `8192px` and my height is `16000px`, i need to draw this on two `TBitmap`).
I am using Delphi 10.2.3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the large image (from a file) to two `TImage` components as follows

Load the image from file to a `TBitmapSurface` as you already do in your code.

Then create another `TBitmapSurface` and set its size to the half of the large one. Copy the first half of the large image to this surface and assign it to `Image1.Bitmap`. Then copy the latter half to this surface and assign that to `Image2.Bitmap`.

```
var
  srce, dest: TBitmapSurface;
  path: string;
  scan: integer;
  w, h1, h2: integer;
begin
  path := 'C:\tmp\Imgs\res.bmp';

  srce := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromFile(path, srce);

    dest := TBitmapSurface.Create;
    try
      // first half
      w := srce.Width;
      h1 := srce.Height div 2;
      dest.SetSize(w, h1, TPixelFormat.RGBA);
      for scan := 0 to h1-1 do
        Move(srce.Scanline[scan]^, TBitmapSurface(dest).Scanline[scan]^, srce.Width * 4);
      Image1.Bitmap.Assign(dest);

      // second half
      h2 := srce.Height - h1;
      dest.SetSize(w, h2, TPixelFormat.RGBA);
      for scan := h1 to srce.Height-1 do
        Move(srce.Scanline[scan]^, TBitmapSurface(dest).Scanline[scan-h1]^, srce.Width * 4);
      Image2.Bitmap.Assign(dest);

    finally
      dest.Free;
    end;
  finally
    srce.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you, Excellent Answer !, everything works as it should.

Comment: You are welcomw, I'm glad I could help.