# Working with large bitmaps in Firemonkey causes error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm unable to create a bitmap with width or height greater than 8192 pixels. This is the maximum texture size defined by DirectX 10 and set in TCanvasD2D.GetAttribute (DefaultMaxTextureSize = 8192;). The problem is, that's not very big. Many photos are larger than that. Is there a way around it or do I just accept that this is the limit? This is not an issue in VCL, where the limit is 65535. I'm using Delphi 10.4.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp : TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.SetSize(100, 8193);
end;
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466186/how-to-load-large-bitmap-in-fmx-fire-monkey

Comment: I don't know what you intend to do, but anyway, I'll tell you what I have achieved. I developed an application for radiology (16 bit/pixel monochrome) where I had to process really very large images (more than 500GB each). For the purpose, I loaded the image in the GPU and wrote the processing code on the GPU. This is a complex task. My application is VCL but that is not important since all image processing is done in the GPU as well as rendering.

Comment: Before off loading to GPU, I made a CPU only equivalent processing. The image was handled as a large in memory array. And a GDI bitmap was created having the size of the viewing area on screen (Typically 1920x1200 with the portion viewable shrinking as needed. With this only memory is the limit.

Comment: Thanks. My application has a kind of object selection window. All objects are drawn on a single image inside a scroll box. The image grows as more objects are added. At some point the bitmap becomes too large. I've now realised that a better way would be to have each object as a separate image object and simply position them in the scroll box, which should solve the problem.